# Do MXML apps using Apache flex 4.9.1 SDK automatically compile with falcon?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, mxml, mxmlc

Did I get the following assumptions right? 
ASC 2.0 is used to compile pure Actionscript projects, 
Falcon is used to compile MXML apps,
Apache Flex 4.9.1 SDK automatically compile using Falcon without any other configurations, 
There is no way to use a Flash builder 4.7 FXP in flash catalyst (regardless the SDK used...)
On the last one, i'd ask - what is your designer/ developer workflow?
Given that you can't use flash catalyst anymore, do you put layout responsibility on the developer? adjusting styles back and forth trying to match the designer mockups, then compile then refresh in the browser?
Does anyone here have a smarter workflow to recommend? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> ASC 2.0 is used to compile pure Actionscript projects,

To be as specific as possible: ASC 2.0 (AKA a version of the Falcon Compiler) is used to compile pure ActionScript projects created with flash Builder 4.7.

> Falcon is used to compile MXML apps,

No, it isn't.  Falcon is not the primary compiler used in Apache Flex.  It has been donated to Apache and work is ongoing with it.  But, Adobe did not complete the MXML compile functionality.  The "old" compiler is still used for Apache Flex.

> Apache Flex 4.9.1 SDK automatically compile using Falcon without any
>   other configurations,

No, that is incorrect (see above).

> There is no way to use a Flash builder 4.7 FXP in flash catalyst
>   (regardless the SDK used...)

I don't actually know this one; but I assume this isn't possible.

> On the last one, i'd ask - what is your designer/ developer workflow?

Designer sends comps usually in Photoshop, or possibly in HTML.  It depends what tool they used for prototyping.  Some programmer--ideally not me--writes the CSS and other styling code needed.

I have no doubt that this sucks;  I never understood how Flash Catalyst would fix that; especially since it was not a "two way" communication.  Designs went from Flash Catalyst to Flash Builder; but not back.

> Given that you can't use flash catalyst anymore, do you put layout
>   responsibility on the developer?

I guess yes; but I never worked on a project using Flash Catalyst.

Comment: Hi There
Any clue on when Falcon could compile mxml apps?
is it possible to try it out for restricted use-cases? if so - how do you configure your flex project to compile with falcon? lastly - if I'm not a compiler engineer - is there a way to contribute and speed up the falcon compiler development?

Comment: Whenever development is finished.  I remember people saying that it was ~70% complete and can compile simple MXML.  If you want to help; I'm sure you're input would be welcome. You'd have to look for more specifics on the Apache Flex dev list.

Comment: Do you know how do you set it to be the compiler, in order to test it?
Thanks

Comment: I've not tried but I at a guess edit or replace the mxmlc/mxmlc.bat and compc/compc.bat in the SDK bin directory. (Depending on the platform you are on)

Comment: @JeffryHouser Is your answer still true?

Comment: @nemi primarily yes.  I'm not sure if the Apache Flex SDK replaced the compiler or not--I did not think it did.  I thought Falcon was used as the base for the Flex to JS projects.